# How to sort the columns in a list in Python

Tags: python

There is a list such like

```
List = [['19-03-2006', 10000 ], 
    ['02-09-2006', 68 ], 
    ['03-07-2006', 300 ], 
    ['03-07-2006', 80 ], 
    ['03-07-2006', 200 ], 
    ['03-07-2006', 30 ]]
```

Try to output like:

```
List =  [['19-03-2006', 30 ]] 
         ['19-03-2006', 10000 ], 
         ['03-07-2006', 300 ],
         ['02-09-2006', 68 ], 
         ['02-09-2006', 80 ],   
         ['15-10-2006', 200 ]]
```

Sort by date first, from earliest to latest, and then by number from lowest to highest.
How can I do this without use modules like a datetime.

Comment: please fix your input to use proper string delimiters

Comment: accept my edit suggestion for a fix on the input

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed already

Comment: Why '03-07-2006' after '02-09-2006'?

Comment: Where does ['19-03-2006', 30 ] come from? That's not in your input. And the output is invalid, due to that early `]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use good old comparator converted to key function. Since Python 3.2, the functools.cmp_to_key() function has been added to standard library

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def comparator(a, b):
    a_date, a_num = a
    b_date, b_num = b
    
    a_date = tuple(map(int, reversed(a_date.split("-"))))
    b_date = tuple(map(int, reversed(b_date.split("-"))))
    
    # By year
    if a_date[0] > b_date[0]:
        return 1
    elif a_date[0] < b_date[0]:
        return -1
    else:
        # By month
        if a_date[1] > b_date[1]:
            return 1
        elif a_date[1] < b_date[1]:
            return -1
        else:
            # By day
            if a_date[2] > b_date[2]:
                return 1
            elif a_date[2] < b_date[2]:
                return -1
            else:
                # By number
                if a_num > b_num:
                    return 1
                elif a_num < b_num:
                    return -1
                else:
                    return 0

data = [
    ['19-03-2006', 10000], 
    ['02-09-2006', 68], 
    ['03-07-2006', 300], 
    ['03-07-2006', 80], 
    ['03-07-2006', 200], 
    ['03-07-2006', 30]
]

sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(comparator))
```

Output:

```
[['19-03-2006', 10000],
 ['03-07-2006', 30],
 ['03-07-2006', 80],
 ['03-07-2006', 200],
 ['03-07-2006', 300],
 ['02-09-2006', 68]]
```

Answer (score 0):

- First thing, use meaningful names for variables
- You can use sorted and a custom key which is the first value of each array properly formatted as a datetime. Sorted will take care of sorting.

  ```
  import datetime

  orders = [['19-03-2006', 10000],
        ['02-09-2006', 68],
        ['03-07-2006', 300],
        ['03-07-2006', 80],
        ['03-07-2006', 200],
        ['03-07-2006', 30]]

  print(sorted(orders, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y')))
  ```

If you want secondary sorting using the value, pass it as well.

```
import datetime
orders = [['19-03-2006', 10000 ],
        ['02-09-2006', 68 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 300 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 80 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 200 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 30 ]]

print(sorted(orders, key=lambda x: (datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'), x[1])))
```

Without using datetime, we can just pass the date to an integer and use that.

```
orders = [['19-03-2006', 10000 ],
        ['02-09-2006', 68 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 300 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 80 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 200 ],
        ['03-07-2006', 30 ]]


def date_to_integer(date):
    day, month, year = map(int, date.split('-'))
    return 10000*year + 100*month + day


print(sorted(orders, key=lambda x: (date_to_integer(x[0]), x[1])))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit the "How can I do this without use modules like a datetime" question.

Comment: What if I don't use datetime? my teacher don't allow me to use this module, lol

Comment: If your teacher doesn't want you to use a module, they probably also don't want you to go ask others to solve this problem for you.

Comment: edited! but please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the first entry in the sublist by just specifying `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])`. You would of course also have to write a function for comparing two datestamps if you don't want to use existing functions (like from datetime and timedelta) to do this.

If you want to sort first with one method, and then with another, you can just provide a tuple as a key, where the first item is your primary order.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an expert on python, but I'd sum up the date strings before converting them into integers.

```py
my_list = [
    ['19-03-2006', 10000],  
    ['02-09-2006', 68],    
    ['03-07-2006', 300],   
    ['03-07-2006', 80],     
    ['03-07-2006', 200],   
    ['03-07-2006', 30]     
]

def date_to_int(date):
    day, month, year = date.split('-')
    return int(year + month + day)

print(sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: (date_to_int(x[0]), x[1])))
```

Result:

```py
[
    ['19-03-2006', 10000], # 20060319 10000
    ['03-07-2006', 30],    # 20060703 30
    ['03-07-2006', 80],    # 20060703 80
    ['03-07-2006', 200],   # 20060703 200
    ['03-07-2006', 300],   # 20060703 300
    ['02-09-2006', 68]     # 20060902 68
]
```